# Page return on android - catch that it was due to the back button being pressed

Tags: java, android

Does a page know that it's being loaded as the result of the back button being pressed? We have a global routine that catches the back button press, gives a notification and then carries on the `super.onBackPressed();`

This is all fine, but theres an instance where the page is jumped forwards in certain situations - so when a back button is pressed before it gets in a loop and forwards the page forward again.

Essentially I want the previous page to have an if around the forward to say in psudo

```
if(page-load-is-a-result-of-the-back-button){
finish(); 
   } else { 
dothejumpforward;
}
```

A lot like .nets if ispostback type thing?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you simply define a workflow that you need and example flow, its a bit confusing

Comment: I just need to know if the page load is a result of the back button being pressed - Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 1 - The second page 1 should know that it's a result of page 2 being closed by the back button

Answer (score 0):

Its simple if your activity gains control back from other activity as a result its `Oncreate` should not get called instead `OnResume` will get called. Put a bool value to check it ,...

Eg: within `OnPause()` set the bool paused = true;

Within `OnResume()`

`If(paused)
  //Its a result`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You make a static variable in your Main Activity, your first activity that is launching with your app. Let's say it will be: `public static int backFromActivity;`

So when you press the back button while you are in Activity2, you will override the `onBackPressed` method, and when this method is called you set the `MainActivity.backFromActivity = 2;`

Now in your `onResume` method from the Activty1 you check from what activity reached this on.
`if ( MainActivity.backFromActivity == 2 ) // do stuff`